# Is it possible to display just the exponent value of a 5-digit number in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the following table and I am attempting to format data in a very specific format.  In order to use the raw value for it's attended function, I must format the raw value, so there are 5 numerical values then the applicable exponent number.  **I cannot use strict scientific notation due  for a verity of reasons.**

Here is a known good example: 0.00011766000000 which would be displayed as: **+11766-3**

Here is another good example: -0.00018002000000 which would be display as: **-18002-3**

In my testing on a larger data set it appears everything is working, however these numbers are used to calculate the orbital rotation of an object, so precision (within the limitations of the format I am using) is important.

| Raw Value | Required Output | Formula | Actual Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.00995253 | +99525-2 | `=CONCATENATE(MID(TEXT(J2,"+.#####00000E+#;-.#####00000E+#"),3,5),RIGHT(TEXT(J2,"+.#####E+#;-.#####E-#"),2))` | 99525-2 |
| -0.00188400 | -18840-5 | See Above | 18840-5 |

My formula only works when the number is positive but it does not work when the value is negative.  If I was only dealing with a couple hundred numbers, I would be able to run some tests on the numbers, but I am dealing with tens of thousands of these numbers.

One solution that might work is detecting if the value is negative or positive, and using a simple conditional statement, to concatenate a negative sign to the string. Likewise, if it's positive, I would concatenate a positive sign to the string.

I believe something like `=IF(B2>=0,CONCATENATE("+",H2),CONCATENATE("-",H2))` would work but I am wondering if I am missing anything?  *B2 is the Raw Data; H2 is the Expected Data*

So I am wondering if there is a way to format the value in the required format that doesn't require text manipulation?  I would rather just format the code the way I need it then use the Text function to capture the desired value.

Comment: If "precision is important", why would you drop digits from the number??

Comment: @Aganju - Precision is required up to a certain decimal place. The expected numerical value must be exactly the following: A sign symbol indicating if the number is positive or negative, 5 digits, then an exponent.  *It cannot be in scientific notation (i.e. 12345E-3)* I suppose I have to be specific, I am attempt to concatenate values from a CSV into a format my system understands (specifically the Two Line Element (TLE) format).  This particular value can only be 8 characters, and must be in exactly column 54-61 (within the TLE).

Comment: 1. The base 10 log would give the exponent part. 2. Take the ABS() of a number to convert negative to positive, then add sign.

Comment: On the second row of the first column, is the minus sign missing?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Why would I use ABS? I want the sign of the raw value, basically I want the scientific notation without the “E” but keeping the value of the exponent (with its sign) and only print 5 digits.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio - No; One of my examples is missing a sign though, corrected that mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to go about getting the correct output slightly differently than what was suggested. I created two formulas to achieve my original goal. I decided to stick with two formulas since I could simply hide the other two columns if I wanted.

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(TEXT(J2,"+.#####00000E+#;-.#####00000E+#"),3,5),RIGHT(TEXT(J2,"+.#####00000E+#;-.#####00000E-#"),2))

=IF(J2>=0,CONCATENATE("+",K2),CONCATENATE("-",K2))
```

| Raw Value | Required Output | Formula 1 | Formula 2 | Actual Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -0.001884 | -18840-2 | See Above | See Above | -18840-2 |
| 0.0099525 | +99525-2 | See Above | See Above | +99525-2 |

While the other solution, technically would have resulted in the correct output, I discovered that I had to explicitly indicate the + and - signs in order for the output in order to use the actual output in my final solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly is the issue with your formula, here is one which I believe is more robust:

```
=IF(A1>0,"+","")& SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( TEXT(A1,"0.0000E+0"),".",""),"E","")
```

[image]

Comment: "I'm not sure what exactly is the issue with your formula" - The formula I provided, does not keep the sign of the number, which means the text is one character short than the required length.  When I have an opportunity to confirm the formula in the morning I will provide some feedback and/or accept this answer.  It appears it will work as required and is exactly what I was looking for to avoid (corner cases) with the RIGHT and MID function.

Comment: At first glance I thought it worked perfectly, but the exponent is off by one, I suspect that is due to the fact '0.1234567` in scientific notation within excel is `1.23456E-1` instead of the required `12345E+0` or `12345E-0`.  It appears I can get around that problem by multiplying by 10.  *I will investigate if that is an acceptable solution.*